# Pi 3 802.1x secured Wi-Fi

Tags: networking, wifi, pi-3, wireless

My school's Wi-Fi is 802.1x with username/password security. I just installed the OS on my PI 3, and after booting up it sees this network, but for some reason it is greyed out. All other networks it sees are not greyed out.

Would someone please tell me why this network is greyed out and, if you could, what steps I can take to connect to this network?